# why is each open set an $F_\sigma$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Royden's Real Analysis:

> On $\mathbb{R}$, a set which is a countable union of closed sets is called an $F_\sigma$. 
>   Thus every countable set is an $F_\sigma$, as is, of course, every closed set. 
>   A countable union of sets in Fa is again in $F_\sigma$. 
>   Since
>   $$(a, b)= \cup_{n=1}^\infty [a + 1/n, b - 1/n],$$
>   each open interval is an $F_\sigma$, and hence each open set is an $F_\sigma$.

Each open interval is an $F_\sigma$, but why is each open set an $F_\sigma$? An open set can be uncountable union of open intervals.

If we are considering a general Borel sigma algebra instead of $B(\mathbb R)$, will each open set be an  $F_\sigma$?

Thanks!

Comment: With regard to your second question, I think you mean a ‘topology’ instead of a ‘Borel $ \sigma $-algebra’. You have to separate topology from measure theory here because your question is purely topological in nature.

Comment: @HaskellCurry: Is studying $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ a topic of purely topological?

Comment: Yes. Their definitions are purely topological.

Comment: Consider the topology on $\mathbb R$ where a set is open iff it is either empty, or if its complement is countable. A closed set is either all of $\mathbb R$, or a countable (possible finite) set. No open set other than $\mathbb R$ is $F_\sigma$.

Comment: @HaskellCurry: Are they of any use in purely topological theory? Are countable operations studied in topology?

Comment: @Ethan: Sure. There is a topological result by S. Mazurkiewicz, which states that for a metrically complete space $ X $ and a subset $ A \subseteq X $, we have that $ A $ is also metrically complete if and only if $ A $ is a $ G_{\delta} $-subset of $ X $.

Comment: @Haskell: who says "metrically complete" for "admits a complete metric"?

Comment: @Martin: According to my definition, a topological space $ (X,\tau) $ is said to be **metrically complete** if and only if there is a complete metric $ d $ on $ X $ such that $ \tau(d) = \tau $.

Comment: @Haskell: Thanks. I didn't ask about the definition. I asked who uses this terminology.

Comment: @Haskell: The usual terms are *topologically complete* and *completely metrizable*.

Comment: @Martin: Isn’t it in Munkres’ *Topology* or something? I can’t really remember, but it’s a terminology that I learned as an undergraduate. :)

Comment: @Haskell: I don't think it's in Munkres. I never saw the term before, that's why I asked. I'm used to what Brian mentions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Every open set in $\Bbb R$ can be written as a union of open intervals with rational endpoints, and there are only countably many such open intervals. Each of them is an $F_\sigma$, so every open set is an $F_\sigma$.

More generally, let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space, and let $U\subseteq X$ be open and non-empty. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $F_n=\{x\in U:d(x,X\setminus U)\ge 2^{-n}\}$; each $F_n$ is closed, and $U=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$. Thus, every open set in a metric space is an $F_\sigma$.

Now let $X$ be the space $\omega_1$ with the order topology. The set $U$ of isolated points of $X$ is open and uncountable. $X$ is countably compact, however, so the only closed subsets of $U$ are the finite subsets, and $U$ cannot be an $F_\sigma$.

Comment: If we are considering a general Borel sigma algebra instead of $B(\mathbb R)$, will each open set be an  $F_\sigma$?

Comment: @Ethan: You mean on an arbitrary space?

Comment: the sigma algebra generated by any topology over any set

Comment: @Ethan: I’ve expanded the answer to show that the answer is *no* in general.

Comment: Open sets in a normal space are $F_\sigma$ if and only if the space is [perfectly normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space)

Answer (score 3):

As a slight expansion of Brian Scott's argument every open set in $\mathbb R$ is the disjoint union of a countable number of open intervals. In particular if $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ then for each $x \in U$ we can consider the largest interval $x \in I_x \subset U$. Then the set $\mathcal I=\{I_x : x \in U\}$ is a disjoint open cover of $U$ whose union is precisely $U$. We see that it's countable from observing that each interval contains a rational so there's an injection from $\mathcal I$ to the rationals.

Comment: This is the way I learned this way back when.  open intervals are connected, so if two intersect their union is an open interval,

Comment: @BarbaraOsofsky, There's also a proof of this fact in Royden not too much further I imagine than where the OP currently is in the book.