# When is every open set a $F_\sigma$?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

My question concerns the $F_\sigma$ property of a topological space $X$. I want to know if there is a particular name for those spaces in which every open set is $F_\sigma$.

Moreover, if $X$ is a metric space the the above property is true, however, what happens if we ask less regularity from the space? Myabe only the axioms of countability can guarantee it?

Also, any reference on the subject is appreciated.

Comment: Here is a reference that has some useful info: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/290114/.  In particular, Martin points out in a comment that among normal spaces, the perfectly normal spaces are the ones in which all open sets are $F_\sigma$s.

Comment: To follow up on Jonas Meyer's comment, [*Some examples in the theory of Borel sets*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm71/fm7131.pdf) by Stephen Willard (yes, this is the Willard who wrote the well known general topology text) has some useful discussions about this issue.