# Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by compact set

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

How can I show that the Borel $\sigma$ algebra is generated by the family $F = \{A \subset \mathbb R : $ A compact$\}$ ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried? You have posted  a number of questions of this type without  prorviding any context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any open set $A$ in $\Bbb{R}$ is $F_{\sigma}$ i.e $A=\bigcup_nF_n$ where $F_n$ are closed.

and also $A=\bigcup_n\bigcup_m (F_n \cap [-m,m])$ where these intersections are compact sets.

So the sigma algebra generated by $F$ contains the borel sigma algebra(which is the smallest sigma algebra generated by the open sets)

Also every compact set is Borel,so $\sigma(F)$ is a subsets of the Borel sigma algebra,by definition of $\sigma (F)$

Comment: why the first statement is correct? do you have a proof for it?

Comment: @Emptymind every open set in $R$ is F sigma and in any metric space is F sigma...you can find a proof of this everywhere.

Comment: @Emptymind look at this for instance.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290114/why-is-each-open-set-an-f-sigma